# Does linking work differently in the simulator than it does in Google Assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm working through account linking on an app and have it working successfully using the URL provided in the Debug tab in the Simulator. It's worth noting that my /authorization endpoint requires an additional query param which I've included in the account linking config due to some additional security requirements.

However, when I try and use my app from within Google Assistant, I get the link button to connect and it opens up the browser window but gives me an error from my server saying I'm missing a required param (the query param included as part of my /authorize endpoint). Any idea why this would be different?

Comment: We had a similar issue with the /auth endpoint months ago.

Long story short, we failed certification because query parameters are not supported for the /authorize endpoint. We contacted the Google support, they confirmed that query parameters are not allowed / supported. This was quite some time ago and a lot has changed since then, so your issue might have a different cause - but your description does sound awfully familiar

Comment: Yup, coincidentally had that confirmed yesterday. Thanks for posting.